# Aggregating Set Type in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to aggregate rows which each contain a column of Set. I would like the result to contain the sum of all sets, where null would be equivalent to the empty set. I expected a query like: "select sum(my_set_column) from my_table group by my_key_column" to do this, but the set type is not supported by this aggregate. Does anyone know of a way to aggregate this using existing cassandra built-ins? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to write a udf (sum a single set) or a uda (sum multiple sets) but it should be pretty straight forward. Something like

```
CREATE FUNCTION set_sum(values set<int>)
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
RETURNS int
LANGUAGE java
AS $$
  if (values == null)
    return 0;

  int total = 0;
  for (int v : values)
    total += v;
  return total;
$$;
```

Then `SELECT set_sum(value_column) FROM my_table WHERE id = 'key';` would aggregate the values of the set column in each row. If you want to merge multiple rows (ie with group by) you need to use a UDA which can use above function with an int state to replace `total` instead of starting from 0 each time.

Comment: I feared this would be the case. Regardless, thank you for your answer, I'll try it out now!

Comment: Actually, what I am looking for is the set addition of the elements, e.g., {1, 3, 5} + {2, 4} = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}. I tried to use a UDF, but this does not preserve state, so I can't accumulate. I tried to use a UDA, but this would require extensive rewrites to all of my queries (which is not feasible) to request the UDA as the column instead of the existing columns. Have you ever written something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work with the following UDF/UDA. This could be considered a general purpose set aggregator if anyone else needs it in the future:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION agg_set_func(state tuple<int, set<bigint>>, val set<bigint>) CALLED ON NULL INPUT RETURNS tuple<int, set<bigint>> LANGUAGE java AS 
$$
    if (val == null) {
        return state;
    }
    Set<Long> s = state.getSet(1, Long.class);
    s.addAll(val);
    state.setSet(1, s);
    return state;
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION agg_set_func_final(state tuple<int, set<bigint>>) CALLED ON NULL INPUT RETURNS set<bigint> LANGUAGE java AS 
$$
    return state.getSet(1, Long.class);
$$;

CREATE AGGREGATE agg_set(set<bigint>) 
SFUNC agg_set_func
STYPE tuple<int, set<bigint>>
FINALFUNC agg_set_func_final
INITCOND (0,{});
```